# Класс String и его метод charAt

Tags: java, строки

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String(new char[]{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'});
        System.out.println(str.charAt(str.length() - 1 ));
    }
}
```

Не понимаю почему выдаёт d, если длина допустим у нас - 11. И мы делаем 11 - 1 = 10 и почему выдает d.

Answer (score 4):

А что ты ожидаешь?

Метод `charAt` класса `String` выдает символ строки по указанному индексу. [Документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

Индексация в строках не с 1, а с 0, поэтому символ с индексом 10 - это 11-ый символ, то есть 'd'.